# Having trouble randomly generating numbers in multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to generate coordinates in a mulidimensional array.

the range for each digit in the coords is -1 to 1.  <=> seems like the way to go comparing two random numbers.  I'm having trouble because randomizing it takes forever, coords duplicate and sometimes don't fill all the way through.  I've tried uniq! which only causes the initialization to run forever while it tries to come up with the different iterations.

the coords look something like this. (-1, 0, 1, 0, 0)

5 digits give position.  I could write them out but I'd like to generate the coords each time the program is initiated.  The coords would then be assigned to a hash tied to a key.  1 - 242.

I could really use some advice.

edited to add code.  It does start to iterate but it doesn't fill out properly.  Short of just writing out an array with all possible combos and randomizing before merging it with the key. I can't figure out how.

```
room_range = (1..241)
room_num = [*room_range]
p room_num
$rand_loc_cords = []

def Randy(x)

    srand(x)
    y = (rand(100) + 1) * 1500
    z = (rand(200) + 1) * 1000
    return z <=> y

end

def rand_loc


   until $rand_loc_cords.length == 243 do
     x = Time.new.to_i
    $rand_loc_cords.push([Randy(x), Randy(x), Randy(x), Randy(x), Randy(x)])
    $rand_loc_cords.uniq!
    p $rand_loc_cords
end

   #p $rand_loc_cords

end

rand_loc
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried please.

Comment: edited with code

Comment: Since your are constantly re-seeding the random number generator with the same value, you will obviously constantly get the same random numbers.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping since the time would change it would help but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get all possible permutations of -1, 0 and 1 with a length of 5 by sheer luck, which can take forever. There are 243 of them (3**5) indeed:

```
coords = [-1,0,1].repeated_permutation(5).to_a
```

[Shuffle](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) the array if the order should be randomized.